# Passing a variable to Handlebars partial

Tags: handlebars.js, partials

Paraphrased example:

`fileA.hbs` has this line of code:

```
{{> partialA offset=1 }}
```

`partialA.hbs` has this line of code:

```
{{> partialB offset=offset }}
```

`partialB.hbs` has this line of code:

```
Offset: {{ offset }}
```

The final file -- `fileA.html` -- only has `Offset:`, not `Offset: 1` as I was expecting.

When I set the `{{> partialB...` line to use `offset=1` it displays `Offset: 1` as expected.

Is there any way for me to pass the `offset` variable to another partial?

*Edit*: clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it seems I actually have a different problem in my code, which I may ask later.

Here's the answer:

```
{{> partialB offset=(offset) }}
```

Uses Handlebars.js 3.0.0's new sub-expressions.